# Number of Requests from Response Code Plugin does not matches to the number from Aggregate Report in jmeter

Tags: jmeter-plugins

I have used **Response code per sec** plugin to check the number of requests failed and exported the result to CSV. After totalling the total number of requests from different response codes,I have observed the number do not matches to the number after completion of the run shown by summarizer/Aggregate report.

Eg: Aggregate Report shows total 2,11,620 requests while response code 1,69,977 (including  Non-HTTP response code: java.net.URISyntaxException) so where are the rest of the requests?? What am I missing?

Comment: Can anyone help over this??

Comment: I still was wondering if anyone could help me over this...